# Connecting isolines (i.e.points of equal value) in 3D scene using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, 3d-analyst, arcscene

I have a point shp theme with fields Lat, Long, Altitude (m), and Number.
The Number field – is a numerical parameter of each point (Lat, Long).

The Altitude field – is the parameter of elevation of each point (Lat, Long) above the surface.

I made a 3d map in ArcScene of ArcGIS10 where I represented each point as a symbol of different size (according to the “Number” field), and then – elevated each point above the surface (according to the “Altitude” field).

Is it possible to connect by isolines (or something like that) all  points of the equal value of the “Number” field (i.e. all points of the same size) in this 3d map?

Comment: I think that I could solve this, if I found a way to create a line consists from many nodes (points) with information of coordinates and altitude of each node. Is it possible to do in ArcGIS?
I think that this type of object (a line from many nodes with information of coordinates, altitude and other fields) does not look like three types of shp ojects that has ArcGIS (it’s something new). Or I can do it by dint of some tools?

Answer (score 1):

- Create a TIN from the 3D points
- Create 2D lines by digitizing the lines in ArcMap, using snapping environment to snap to the points you want.
- Use the Interpolate Shape tool to create 3D lines using the 2D lines and the TIN surface as input.